# Is it OK to use comparison operators against values of an enum?

Tags: vb.net, enums, comparison-operators

In VB.Net, I typically create Enums like so:

```
Private Enum Zone
  IsNegative = -3
  IsBad = -2
  IsError = -1
  Undefined = 0 ' or Unknown, Nothing...
  Value1
  Value2
  ValueN
End Enum
```

This looks to be in alignment with the [Enum Framework Design Guidelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/enum).
Recently, I started to ensure that also the `Undefined` or `Nothing` value gets the value of 0 assigned so that comparisons like the following work correctly:

```
Dim enu as Zone
If enu = Nothing Then ...
```

`Nothing` is 0, this matches the `Nothing` or `Undefined` value of the `Enum`.
Often, and because I always assign negative values to error, wrong, or somehow bad values, I also do comparisons like:

```
If enu > 0 Then
' Perform something with the Zone Enum knowing it's a correct value
Else
  ' Handle the Enum error or correct its value
End If
```

This allows testing against all the values of the Enum that are good at once.

Is this good practice, or should I never compare an Enum numerically? Are there reasons why this should be avoided?

Comment: You could use powers of 2 for some or all of your fields and then all the fields that currently have negative values could include the same power of 2. You could then look for that specific power of 2 and it would match multiple values.

Comment: `Dim enu As Zone = Nothing` is the same as the C#  `Zone enu = default;` version. So no problem with that or the comparison with values `<=> 0` (the same applies to C#). You could be explicit and set `Private Enum Zone As Integer` (though that's the default, too).

Answer (score 0):

Enum is more of systematic styling approach of using known values. Your way is not wrong but instead of that you could still use constants or some other variables or direct values, but for the sake of readability and code maintainability, it is recommended, you use enum the way enumerators should be used.

```
If yourvalue = enu.Undefined then ...
```

Comment: Indeed, but that only works for single values. I know of no better way than what I outlined in my question to do a comparison against a group of `Enum` values. `If Not SomeValue = enu.Value1 And Not SomeValue = enu.Value2 And Not ...` is quite unwieldy.

Comment: see Enum.IsDefined() . Hope that helps.